# Multiple databases in Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Firstly, I'm new to Python.

Now that that's out of the way. I'm trying to access data on 2 different databases and display information on one view.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/models.html#multiple-databases

This^ seems incomplete after the first paragraph. I have the first database working and complete, and it works great. Now I'm trying to incorporate a second database.

I can't find anywhere what my development.ini file should look like if I have a second database. I have this:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mssql+pyodbc://[databasestuffsredacted]
```

and I figured something like

```
db2 = mssql+pyodbc://[seconddbstuffsredacted]
```

(both databases use the same type and driver) From a [previous stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050579/changing-database-per-view-accessing-multiple-databases-per-view), this was mentioned:

```
DBSession2 = orm.scoped_session(orm.sessionmaker(extension=ZTE())
```

But, how in the world does that talk to my second database. I'm missing a crucial piece here that I think should have been in the document above after the first paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can write it in a module

```
engine= create_engine('postgresql://user:pswd@localhost/db1')
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)

engine2= create_engine('postgresql://user:pswd@localhost/db2')
DBSession2 = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
DBSession2.configure(bind=engine2)
```

Comment: I assume that information would go in my init.py, so I would just remove the db info from my development.ini?

Comment: you can add it in models.py, or create package models then write a new module in it.